Elite warriors who have never lost must fight near trees
This book has a young boy who is sent as a hostage to stay with an elite group of warriors. These warriors have never lost a battle, but they must fight within sight of a tree and then during the battle the tree will take all their injuries leaving the warriors unharmed.
At some point the boy is able to go home and those he returns to are interested in any information he can give about the warriors and how they do what they do. This book gives medieval vibes, so not overly magical. I feel like I remember that each warrior had some special skill. Sound family to anyone?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   When did you read this?  Was it a paperback, hardcover or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Hi so I'm a librarian and this is a customer question. I personally think she is talking about the Name of the wind series, specifically a scene that takes place in the 2nd book. But she is sure it was not these books, and she said she has read the Robin Hobb soldier son trilogy and it isn't those either. I appreciate all the suggestions.

Is it possible that you're thinking of Robin Hobb's Soldier Son Trilogy, specifically the second book, Forest Mage?

The career of a person living in Gernia is heavily influenced by their parentage. Those sons born to common parentage follow their father's career. However, for the sons of a noble, things are different. The eldest son inherits his father's title, the second son serves as an officer in the army, the third son enters priesthood, while the fourth becomes an artist. This allocation continues for further sons. Daughters are relegated to submissive roles, being primarily used to forge social links with arranged marriages.

....

Book two, Forest Mage, concerns Nevare's trip in disgrace to a town near Gettys, and his time at this farthest outpost in the King's Road construction. His connection with the Specks, a race of tree people who live on after their corporeal lives, develops further. The changes imposed to his body by the Specks' magic he wields, causes rejection and discrimination by most Gernians, including his family. In spite of it, he still pursues his dream of a military career. At the same time, he also tries to save the Specks' ancestors forest from the devastations produced by the Gernian's road advance.

The Specks have tree magic, although it primarily involves drawing power from the trees for use later (which also results in weight gain, an issue between Nevare and his father).
Found with a search for fantasy novel warriors trees take their injuries

Unaccepted answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100790/looking-for-a-fantasy-book-series-where-dying-people-are-absorbed-by-trees

I don't think the first book deals with the Specks very much. Being dedicated to Nevare getting through the first year of the academy. I also don't recall any of the other aspects mentioned in the question. Certainly not anyone training with the Specks and returning.

@Jontia: Ah, I think I read the summary incorrectly. The second book does seem to be about his time with the Specks. I will modify my answer, although I'm really not certain that this is a right answer, just one close enough that I figure it's worth mentioning.
